# Discord Button interaction

Tags: python, button, discord.py, bots

I use discord.py ver 2.0.1

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    button1 = Button(label='Logout', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji='<:158667290_184837826776331_547475:1061360212117827745>')

    
    async def callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.send('Hi')

    button.callback = callback

    view = View()
    view.add_item(button1)
    await ctx.send(view=view)
```

Nothing if i press at button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
await interaction.response.send('Hi')
```

[`InteractionResponse.send` doesn't exist](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interactionresponse#discord.InteractionResponse) so you can't expect it to do anything. The method to send a message is [`InteractionResponse.send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interactionresponse#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message), as the name implies.

You should've gotten an error message that told you this. If you didn't, you're either swallowing errors in an error handler or you didn't [configure logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html?highlight=logging).